# python '_mysql_connector' 'convert_to_mysql' method get exception when given string with character � in linux server

Tags: python, mysql, linux, mysql-connector

I'm running the following script in a linux server:

```
import _mysql_connector

ccnx = _mysql_connector.MySQL()
ccnx.connect(user=<user_name>, database=<db_name>, password=<pass>, host=<host>)
bad_str = 'just_an_��_example'

try:
    str_converted = ccnx.convert_to_mysql(*[bad_str])
    print('str converted is %s', str_converted)
except Exception as e:
    print('cant convert bad str %s',bad_str)
    print(e)
```

The script get exception **"Failed converting Python 'str'"**.

I've tried to add encoding exports before running the script:

- export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
- export LANG=en_US.utf-8

It didn't work as well..

The issue also reproduced the issue in macos terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with version 8.0.21 of mysql-connector-python.  I got it to work by reverting to mysql-connector-python 8.0.12.